# MatrixFree Linear Operators vs. Sparse Arrays

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, scientific-computing

How to quantify the  performance of matrix-free operators and sparse arrays for matrix-vector products. Specifically, what is speed cost of having matrix-vector products dominated by function calls than by array addressing.

I'm solving a linear system arising from a PDE using iterative methods. Matrix-free methods have no memory issues and looks efficient for my case.

May be for a single matrixfree A wins(unless the function representing A is overkilled by internal computations), but how compositions and superposition of matrixfree operators behave.

Comment: In general, sparse array indexing is relatively inefficient, so matrix-free methods will be better. It's hard to give a good answer without specifics though